# How can I preserve line breaks from EditText?

Tags: android

The following ignore new lines when I display them

```
private void post() {
        String subject = "";
        String message = "";
        subject = etSubject.getText().toString();
        message = etMessage.getText().toString();
```

edit: My edittext is already set to multiline however when I write multilined text in it it's returned as a single line with the cover above

edit2: i am getting the text from an editText and displaying it on a textview

Comment: Would you post more of your code? What you have shouldn't ignore new line characters.

Comment: You can also achieve this functionality by https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753731/6676310

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solved it by using `replaceAll("\\n", "<br />")`

```
message = etMessage.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\n", "<br />")
```

Comment: God Bless you! thanks, I just got a problem when I need to transform the message using html.toHtml, I must create a Spannable, but in this processs the <br/> get lost =/

Comment: God bless you! you saved my time!

Comment: But if orginal content used Enter for each new line how we can preserve that line break?

Comment: I have tried but its don't work. then after I use this solution & its work like a charm. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753731/6676310

Answer (score 2):

Use the `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` property... Set it in xml or Eclipse Gui

Comment: Where are you setting the text...is it another EditText or TextView

Answer (score 1):

try adding `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` if you are displaying it in a TextView also add 
`android:singleLine="false"` to your EditText definition.

**Edit :**

It's your EditText that should have `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` for example:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/myDisplayingTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
       android:singleLine="false"
/>
```

Comment: are you writing it and displaying it in a TextView ? if so your text view should have android:inputType="textMultiLine"

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
editText.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should works

```
message = etMessage.getText().toString().replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, Try this,
    `val msg = evMsg.text.toString().replace("\\n".toRegex(), "<br />")`

Answer (score -2):

```
String text=editText1.getText().toString().replace("\n", " ").trim();
```